# My javascript is not working in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to make my menu to be responsive but 
my javascript is not working on XAMPP. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<html>
<title>The Forerunner</title>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/js/menu.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

<div id="banner">

    <img src="img/TheForerunner.png">

</div>

    <span class="menu-trigger">MENU</span>

    <ul class="nav">

        <li><a href="news.php">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="editorial.php">EDITORIAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="features.php">FEATURES</a></li>
        <li><a href="devcomm.php">DEVCOMM</a></li>
        <li><a href="literary.php">LITERARY</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.php">SPORTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="entertainment.php">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>

    </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

and I don't get any error on my browser's console. I'm using google chrome

```js
$("span.menu-trigger").click(function() {
  $("ul.nav").toggle();
});
```

When I run it I can't click the menu.
I don't get any error on my console.

Comment: any error message in console?

Comment: Did you check your browser's network tab to confirm if the files were loaded?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way => `src="http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"`. You dont need the `http://127.0.0.1` part , you should provide the path relative to the app root.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Do those elements exist? Have you put the jQuery code inside a document.ready handler? `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: Post the total code. The HTML with `span.menu-trigger` and `ul.nav` is missed in your question.

Comment: any error in your browser console? Also html code is required too

Comment: is it working without Xampp

Comment: check the path of your scripts seems wrong to me.

Comment: Also elements don't exist when your code is run. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: where did you put this project?

Comment: I check my browser's console, I don't have any error

Comment: I put my project inside the htdocs folder

Comment: put your click function inside $(document).ready

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find assigning hostnames to development sites eases all this pain!

Simply add this to your hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc (remember you may need to edit the file as administrator to to that):

```
127.0.0.1 sitename
```

Then go to the directory XAMPP is installed, browse to apache\conf\extra and add the following (using your own paths) to your httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName sitename
 DocumentRoot D:\HTML\yoursite
 <Directory D:\HTML\yoursite>
 IndexOptions +FancyIndexing NameWidth=*
 Options Includes FollowSymLinks Indexes
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can simply browse to "http://sitename" and reference all includes from simply "/" which will then work locally and remotely without trouble.

Remember to restart Apache from the xampp control panel after you have made the edits. Also be aware you can have as many of these aliases as you like. I even install Firefox's "server switcher" extension, so I can snap backwards and forwards from local to remote on bunches of sites.

Comment: Hi Kim. Above where you see "sitename" replace that (total of once in each snippet) with anything you like. I tend to use initials of the live domain, so mysupersite.com would be mss - But it's entirely up to you. It is NOT the name of your html file (which is likely index.html I suppose), it's a domain name (so to speak)

Where you see D:\HTML\yoursite you put the path to your local files.

I think most "beginners" have their sites inside the XAMPP directory, but there is no need to do that, you can have it anyway in your own structure. I have all my sites under "HTML" on my D drive.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a relative path to your files. Because the url is most likely "localhost".

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
```

If this still doesn't work make sure your javascript files are in the correct folder. With the above code i assume your javascript files are at the root of your project inside a directory called `js`

Comment: still doesn't work. my javascript is indie the js folder and the js folder is inside the htdocs.

Comment: @Kim Russel Flores can you show us a printscreen of your folder structure?

Comment: I can't post an image but here the link folder for javascript. C:\xampp\htdocs\js

Comment: and where is the above file located ? is its path: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php ?

Comment: and are you trying to load header.php inside a index.php file ?, because if  that's the case it will be the issue because you are trying to load a full html structure inside another html structure probably.

Comment: i know that. but when you load the browser it will look for a index.php file , do you have a include('header.php') inside that file? because if that is the case it will load 2 html sturctures and that will most likely be your issue

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to add in the localhost address

```
src="http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"
```

Instead link to your file like you have done with your css

```
src="../js/menu.js"
```